# Connecting from Azure App Service to Key Vault using managed identity

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-security

If I set up an azure app service to use managed identity eg

```
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential())
```

Is the connection from the Azure app service to the key vault going over the public internet? I read things like "the communication typically stays within Azure's internal network without going over the public internet"! What does that mean?

OR

Do I need to use "Private endpoint connections" for the keyvault?

Comment: What is the framework and version of your App?

Comment: I'm running .net 6

Comment: so the question is not really related to key vault + managed identity ? more a general azure networking question ?

Comment: App Service with KeyVault will not expose any connections over the network.Private endpoint connections is not mandatory, It adds an extra layer of security.

Comment: if you don't use private endpoint, it will use MS internal network are both resources are in MS datacenters.

Answer (score 0):

> "the communication typically stays within Azure's internal network without going over the public internet"!

- It clearly says that the communication between the Azure services (Key Vault/Managed Identity/App Service) will be done within the internal network.
- The data transfer between the Azure Key Vault and the App Service is encrypted by TLS.
- The application has to be authenticated with the Azure Key Vault to get the access.

> Do I need to use "Private endpoint connections" for the keyvault?

As I already mentioned in comment, Using Private endpoint connections is not mandatory. It is completely based on your requirement and configurations.

- Sometimes it is necessary to avoid the Key Vault using Public endpoints.

***Using Private Endpoints:***

- We need to create `Virtual Network` and `Subnet` which we can use to put our Private Endpoints for the Key Vault.

[image]

- In `Azure App Service` => `Networking` => `Outbound traffic configuration`, configure the Virtual network integration.

[image]

Comment: `It clearly says that the communication between the Azure services (Key Vault/Managed Identity/App Service) will be done within the internal network.` => this is only true if private endpoint is enable